# Array of data within foreach with total

Tags: php, arrays, count

Is there a simple way that I can create an array within my foreach to allow me to show how many items from the blacklist have been removed?

**Result Expected:**

guest.booking.com 5

N/A 10

etc

**Code:**

```
$blacklist = ['@guest.booking.com', '@booking.com', 'N/A', 'n.c@hotel.com', 'n.c@hotels.com'];
$blacklistedEmails = false;

    foreach ($blacklist as $b) {

        if (stripos($row->guestEmail, $b) !== false) {
            $blacklistedEmails = true;
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: do you want to count the occurrence of array_item

Comment: you could also `$i = 0;` outside the `foreach` and then `$i++;` inside the `if`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just collect the matches in an associative-keyed result array.  You don't seem interested in the `0` count elements, so they are not generated in the output.

Checking `isset()` is important to avoid generating Notices on the first occurrence of a matched blacklist value.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/OvGDB))

```
$rows = [
    (object)["guestEmail" => "you@booking.com"],
    (object)["guestEmail" => "you@okay.com"],
    (object)["guestEmail" => "me@booking.com"],
    (object)["guestEmail" => "n/a"],
    (object)["guestEmail" => "somebodyelse@booking.com"],
    (object)["guestEmail" => "youAgain@BOOKING.COM"]
];
$blacklist = ['@guest.booking.com', '@booking.com', 'N/A', 'n.c@hotel.com', 'n.c@hotels.com'];

foreach ($rows as $row) {
    foreach ($blacklist as $b) {
        if (stripos($row->guestEmail, $b) !== false) {
            if (isset($blacklistedcounts[$b])) {  // this important to avoid Notices
                ++$blacklistedcounts[$b];  // increment after the element key exists
            } else {
                $blacklistedcounts[$b] = 1;  // set 1 on first occurrence
            }
            break;  // no need to check for other matches for this guestEmail
        }
    }
}
var_export($blacklistedcounts);
```

Output:

```
array (
  '@booking.com' => 4,
  'N/A' => 1,
)
```

---

If for some reason you wish to see the zero values too, you can use `array_fill_keys()`, avoid the `isset()` conditional, and just use `++` incrementation syntax.

```
$blacklistcounts = array_fill_keys($blacklist, 0);
... then inside the stripos() condtion ...
++$blacklistedcounts[$b];
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the count of the blacklisted emails, you'll need to remove the `break` inside your `for` loop, like this:

```
$blacklist = ['@guest.booking.com', '@booking.com', 'N/A', 'n.c@hotel.com', 'n.c@hotels.com'];
$blacklistedEmails = false;
$blacklistCount = 0;

    foreach ($blacklist as $b) {

        if (stripos($row->guestEmail, $b) !== false) {
            $blacklistedEmails = true;
            $blacklistCount++;
        }
    }
```

This will give you the count of the blacklisted emails in `$blacklistCount`.  If you need an array of all the blacklisted items, you could do this:

```
$blacklist = ['@guest.booking.com', '@booking.com', 'N/A', 'n.c@hotel.com', 'n.c@hotels.com'];
$blacklistedEmails = false;
$blackEmails = [];

    foreach ($blacklist as $b) {

        if (stripos($row->guestEmail, $b) !== false) {
            $blacklistedEmails = true;
            $blackEmails[] = $row->guestEmail;
        }
    }
```

This would give you an array of blacklisted emails in `$blackEmails`.  Then you could just use:

```
$blacklistCount = count($blackEmails);
```

That would give you the array and a count.

Comment: These snippets should not be used.  The first will generate Notices and the second doesn't store the element from the blacklist (which is what the OP asked for).  Furthmore, the `break` is an important component as a matter of best practices.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you mean, because its pretty basic but code below seems to do what you want.

```
<?php
$blacklist = ['@guest.booking.com', '@booking.com', 'N/A', 'n.c@hotel.com', 'n.c@hotels.com'];
$blacklistedEmails = false;

$blacklistCount = array();
foreach ($blacklist as $b){
    $blacklistCount[$b] = 0;;
}

foreach ($blacklist as $b) {
    if (stripos("james@booking.com", $b) !== false) {
        $blacklistCount[$b] += 1;
        break;
    }
}
 print_r($blacklistCount);

?>
```

Produces this output..

```
Array
(
    [@guest.booking.com] => 0
    [@booking.com] => 1
    [N/A] => 0
    [n.c@hotel.com] => 0
    [n.c@hotels.com] => 0
)
```

Obviously you need to loop through your email list to count the hits on each blacklisted item. I have just shown one example.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have a bunch of rows that you are running through this check (otherwise I don't see how you'd ever have a count > 1).

A simple way to get the count of the hits for each email is to create an associative array using the blacklisted email as the key and the count as the value.  When you iterate through your loop, just increment the value of the key.

```
$blacklist = ['@guest.booking.com', '@booking.com', 'N/A', 'n.c@hotel.com', 'n.c@hotels.com'];
$blacklistedEmailCounts = [];


foreach ($rows as $row){
    foreach ($blacklist as $b) {

        if (stripos($row->guestEmail, $b) !== false) {
            $blacklistedEmailCounts[$b]++;
        }
    }
}
```

To output the values you could just do something like:

```
foreach($blacklistedEmailCounts as $email=>$count){
    echo "$email: $count" . '<br>';
}
```

Comment: This solution should not be used because it will generate Notices.

Comment: It's simple..!  And could easily be changed to avoid notices.